# Jquery Statements Crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using jquery to animate numbers when the target value is true . but when the value gets true or even gets false my navigation jquery else statement code stops working for some reason i don't know why.i think i'm using "offset" in both.

my html animate numbers

```
 <div class="container" id="counter">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3 class="dark-blue">SOME FACTS ABOUT US WHAT WE ARE</h3>
      </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 top-spacing">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu tellus a nulla rhoncus imperdiet.<br/> Vestibulum quis dictum leo.Curabitur viverra sagittis velit non fringilla. Etiam sed fringilla risus, vel dapibus nisi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center content top-spacing">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-5x color-red"></i>
        <h3 id="bike" class="countdown">0</h3>
        <h3 class="blog-item">Km ride bike</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-5x color-red"></i>
        <h3 id="coffee" class="countdown">0</h3>
        <h3 class="blog-item">Cups of coffee</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-5x color-red"></i>
        <h3 id="projects" class="countdown">0</h3>
        <h3 class="blog-item">Projects Completed</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x color-red"></i>
        <h3 id="users" class="countdown">0</h3>
        <h3 class="blog-item">Users Satisfied</h3>
      </div>
    </div><br/><br/><br/>
  </div>
```

Js for Animate Numbers

```
var target = $("#counter").offset().top-$(window).height();
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > target) {
        $('#bike').animateNumber({ number: 165 },5000);
        $('#coffee').animateNumber({ number: 2165 },5000);
        $('#projects').animateNumber({ number: 385 },5000);
        $('#users').animateNumber({ number: 315 },5000);
        $(this).off('scroll');
    }
});
```

my navigation html

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand-font-size navbar-brand" href="#">Aston</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

CSS for Jquery

```
.navbar-default.scrolled{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB9BE;
  box-shadow: 0,0,2px,#BBB9BE;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 700ms linear;
  transition: background-color 700ms linear;
}
```

JS for Navigation

```
  var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#3F4474"
    });
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar").css({
        "background-color": "#3F4474"
    });
   }
   else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
        "color": "#fff"
    });
    $(".navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar").css({
        "background-color": "#fff"
    });
  }
 });
```

i just want to make the navigation back to its original position with the background color transparent. thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean your `else` stops working? Is there an error message?

Comment: What is the target value that makes the code crash when false?

Comment: alright here is the situation when the navigation "if" statement is triggered. navigation's style gets changed , it turns into white background and the border bottom 1px solid . but when it reaches the area where animate number jquery code gets triggered my navigation "else" statement stops working even if i leave animate number area . and in my else statement i want my navigation get to its original form which has a background color "transparent" when scrolled to top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your current code related to `animateNumber()` relies on `$(this).off('scroll');` to stop the animation of the numbers from going on indefinitely. What you may not understand is how `$(this).off('scroll');` does this.

It prevents your `animateNumber()` from getting called over and over again by removing the `scroll` handler after the first time the code is called. Unfortunately, `$(this).off('scroll');` removes **all** `scroll` handlers that are bound to `document` including the one that modifies your nav bar's `css`

**There are at least 2 ways you can solve this issue**

- dont bind your second handler when the page loads, instead put the second handler inside a function and call it to bind the handler **after** you remove the first handler as shown in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/f60r0eqd/)
- or (my preferred method) put all your code in one `scroll` function and use a variable and an if statement to prevent the infinite loop with `animateNumber()` as shown in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/f60r0eqd/1/)

---

**Here is the jQuery for the second method:**

```
  var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
  var target = $("#counter").offset().top - $(window).height();
  var hasAnimated = false; // add this var
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > target && !hasAnimated) { // check `hasAnimated` is false
          hasAnimated = true; // set to true, next time around this code wont be called
          $('#bike').animateNumber({
              number: 165
          }, 5000);
          $('#coffee').animateNumber({
              number: 2165
          }, 5000);
          $('#projects').animateNumber({
              number: 385
          }, 5000);
          $('#users').animateNumber({
              number: 315
          }, 5000);
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
          $('.navbar-default').addClass("scrolled");
          $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
              "color": "#3F4474"
          });
          $(".navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar").css({
              "background-color": "#3F4474"
          });
      } else {
          $('.navbar-default').removeClass("scrolled");
          $(".navbar-default .navbar-brand").css({
              "color": "#fff"
          });
          $(".navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar").css({
              "background-color": "#fff"
          });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir . it really helped me i'm new in js so i was stuck . Thanks